# Mongodb return old document

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

**Mongodb return old document** 
Hello, friends
Would you be so kind to help me with updating and returning updated ducument? 
Why `mondodb` return old document, what I have missed. 
Here is my code

```
router.post("/user-add-change", (req, res, next) => {
    const data = { fullName: "John" };
    const query = { googleId: "11288970sdvsdv724402783" };
    const update = { data };
    const options = { new: true, upsert: true };

    User.findOneAndUpdate(query, update, options, function(err, doc) {

        console.log(doc.fullName == "John"); //false
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you mean:

```
 const update = { $set: data };
```